# XML Android positioning Layout

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I'm trying to reposition my android app layout, I have 2 x EditText and one Button.

I want to place them below each other, its now side to side.
Here is my code :

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/borderlayout" >

             <EditText
            android:id="@+id/titleText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Title" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/descriptionText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/titleText1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Description" /> 

       <Button
                android:id="@+id/inputbutton1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/descriptionText1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button" />
</TableRow>
```

and this is how it looks when i RUN ( cant post image yet because of low Rep)
http://prntscr.com/3qyjpv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a `LinearLayout` with `orientation=vertical`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

         <EditText
        android:id="@+id/titleText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Title" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/descriptionText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleText1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Description" /> 

   <Button
            android:id="@+id/inputbutton1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/descriptionText1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this to a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you shouldn't use tables for formatting in HTML, so you shouldn't use TableLayout to format the GUI in Android. Reserve your use of TableLayout for formatting data tables.

You can use LinearLayout, if you want, but I prefer to use  to "enforce" the position of widgets relative to each other.